# Fiddler - Unable to capture https traffic

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, fiddler

I have installed fiddler on server named `server1.corp.mycompany.net`. When i browse from my local machine to `https://server1/default.aspx`, it does not capture the traffic. But if i open IE on the server and browse `https://server1/default.aspx`, it works.

I have enabled "Capture https traffic". This is how it looks like:

[image]

Am i missing something?

I am using `Fiddler4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to install Fiddler on your local machine if you expect to capture traffic to the server from your local machine. That's how Fiddler works by default, it only captures traffic originating from browsers on your computer.

If you wanted to inspect all traffic coming to the server, then something like Wireshark would be more appropriate.

Comment: Using Wireshark is unlikely to be useful, since HTTPS traffic is encrypted, and decrypting it is very non-trivial.

Comment: @EricLaw While I have not done so myself, their documentation makes it sound like it's [not too difficult](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL), and provides step by step instructions that look pretty easy to follow. Their documentation says "The SSL dissector is fully functional and even supports advanced features such as decryption of SSL if the encryption key can be provided and Wireshark is compiled against GnuTLS (rather than OpenSSL or bsafe). This works for RSA private keys."

Comment: *Easy to follow* is questionable. This configuration requires you expose the private key (often against policy), and it requires the use of RSA.

Comment: @EricLaw I don't think easy to follow is questionable. Security is however debatable. But for development purposes in a corporate environment where changing the key is trivial and it's simple to generate a new one and have it signed by your CA I don't think this is too bad. And judging by the question, this looks to be a corporate environment.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are:

1. Run Fiddler on the client machine. It will show outbound requests *from* that machine.
2. Run Fiddler on one machine and point the proxy settings on another machine to that first machine. Fiddler will show outbound requests from any client whose proxy settings point at Fiddler.
3. Run Fiddler as a [reverse proxy](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy). This will show inbound requests to the target.

Based on your scenario, you probably want #3.